# Heatmap values are lapsing in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, analytics

I'm using latest version (7.0.1) of Highcharts API. I want to see my datas on Highcharts heatmap. After I set my datas, everything is working nicely except that when I hover over datas, it is shown 3 point further left values in tooltip and hover effect is not working. I am also showing date and time in that tooltip and they are correct. So the problem is with values.

When I change `boostThreshold` and `turboThreshold` values, deactive them, I see true values and hover effect start working but after change my mouse position hover effect is staying and changing its orginal color. And I try to disable hover effect and it is not working too.

In the example heatmap the value should have been **66**

This is how I initialize the heatmap.

```
heatmap = Highcharts.chart('heatmap', {
                chart: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FBFCFD',
                    type: 'heatmap',
                    inverted: true
                },
                boost: {
                    useGPUTranslations: true
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Aktif Tüketim Haritası',
                    margin: 5,
                    style: {"font-family": "titillium_websemibold"}

                },
                xAxis: {
                    endOnTick: true,
                    startOnTick: true,
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 30,
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value:%d %B}'
                    },
                    reversed: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    heatmap: {
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    minPadding: 0,
                    maxPadding: 0,
                    min: 0.0,
                    max: 23.0
                },
                colorAxis: {
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'white'],
                        [0.25, 'YellowGreen'],
                        [0.50, 'yellow'],
                        [0.75, 'DarkOrange'],
                        [1, 'Maroon']
                                /*[0, '#3060cf'],
                                 [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
                                 [0.9, '#c4463a'],
                                 [1, '#c4463a']*/
                    ],
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value} kVA'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    symbolWidth: 550
                },
                exporting: {enabled: false},
                series: [{
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        },
                        boostThreshold: 100,
                        turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
                        colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: 'Aktif Tüketim<br/>',
                            pointFormatter: function () {
                                var decs = this.y.toString().split(".");
                                var minute;
                                if (!decs[1]) {
                                    minute = '00';
                                } else {
                                    minute = Math.round(parseInt(decs[1].padEnd(2, "0")) * 60 / 100);
                                    minute = minute.toString().padStart(2, "0");
                                }
                                var real = decs[0] + ':' + minute;
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b, %Y', new Date(this.x)) + ':' + real + ':<b>' + this.value + '</b> kVA ';
                            },
                        }
                    }]

            });
```

Thanks in advance!

[image: example heatmap]

[code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aL7n9wpj/15/)

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in online code editor like jsfiddle (the above code doesn't have data)?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I update my question and added jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip has strange behavior because you haven't set `rowsize` which is equal to 1 by default. Check demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
  series: [{
    //boostThreshold: 100,
    turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    borderWidth: 0,
    nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
    colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
    rowsize: 0.1666666666,
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: 'Aktif Tüketim<br/>',
      pointFormatter: function() {
        var decs = this.y.toString().split(".");
        var minute;
        if (!decs[1]) {
          minute = '00';
        } else {
          minute = Math.round(parseInt(decs[1].padEnd(2, "0")) * 60 / 100);
          minute = minute.toString().padStart(2, "0");
        }
        var real = decs[0] + ':' + minute;
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b, %Y', new Date(this.x)) + ':' + real + ':<b>' + this.value + '</b> kVA ';
      }
    }
  }]
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6jufyeb8/1/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.rowsize